# How to get dynamic HTML Tabs

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

I have a basic HTML Page having a table with 2 columns & 2 rows.
I want to convert this 2 columns as tabs and on click of each row it should also show a paragraph or one more basic table with 1 row & column.

Everything should happen in the first table itself.

How can I do this? Should I use jQuery? Any fiddle link would be greatful.

```
<table width="100%" id="table" class="table" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td><div contenteditable>tab1</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable>tab2</div></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
    <td><div contenteditable>tab1 info</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable>tab2 info</div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and, please, give a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have added the sample code. Sure I will look into and improve my next questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is exactly what you wanted to reach, but here's a short  [--> fiddle <--](http://jsfiddle.net/tonimxs/6m6f4Lhd/1/)

You will need to use javascript.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tab"><div contenteditable>tab1</div></td>
    <td class="tab not-active"><div contenteditable>tab2</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable class="tab-content">tab1 info</div>
      <div contenteditable class="tab-content not-active">tab2 info</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.tab-content.not-active {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.tab').on('click', function () {
    $('.tab').toggleClass('not-active');
    $('.tab-content').toggleClass('not-active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Yes i am looking for this. But one last thing is I should also be able to click on tab1 info/tab2 info. onClick should again show a 2x2 table with sample data. I tried to do it, but I am getting error.